# Class 'App\Category' not found CategoriesController.php

Tags: php, laravel

I do not know how to solve this.  I get an Error. I am trying to dynamically save the category in the database. But when I press create category I get an error. I am following a course that has a previous laravel version so I am not sure where the problem is.

Class 'App\Category' not found

CategoriesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Category as ModelsCategory;



class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        
        return view('categories.index')->with('categories', Category::all());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('categories.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|unique:categories'
        ]);

        $ncategory = new Category();

        Category::create([
            'name' => $request->name
        ]);

        return redirect(route('categories.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Category.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Comment: Change the namespace in use statement from `App\Category` to `App\Models\Category`

Comment: `use App\Category;` to `use App\Models\Category;`

Comment: if the solution solved your problem , you can accept my answer using "tick"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two different import for Category

```
use App\Category;
use App\Models\Category as ModelsCategory;
```

remove The top one. and change the second one as follow:

```
use App\Models\Category;
```

Answer (score -2):

use App\Models\Category;
It should work

Comment: This does not add anything to Abilogos answer